# Concat strings with a grouped having query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following table

| row_num | ref | value | sub_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ref1 | value1 | sub1 |
| 2 | ref1 | value1 | sub2 |
| 1 | ref2 | value1 | sub2 |
| 2 | ref2 | value2 | sub1 |
| 3 | ref2 | value2 | sub3 |
| 4 | ref2 | value4 | sub1 |
| 1 | ref2 | value1 | sub2 |
| 2 | ref2 | value2 | sub1 |

and a query like this

```
select ref
from t
group by ref
having countif(value = 'value1') > 0 and
       countif(value = 'value2' or sub_value = 'sub1') > 0;
```

What I want to be able to do is also have a field with the concatenated 'value' field for each ref number. So output would be

| ref | value_concat |
| --- | --- |
| ref1 | value1 |
| ref2 | value1, value2, value4 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `string_agg()`:

```
select ref, string_agg(value)
from t
group by ref
having countif(value = 'value1') > 0 and
       countif(value = 'value2' or sub_value = 'sub1') > 0;
```

That said, I recommend `array_agg()` so you have an array of values rather than a string.

Comment: Thanks, I'm wanting to return the csv value so I can directly print that. Do you know how I can remove duplicates? EDIT - ignore that, I can just do `string_agg(DISTINCT value),`